# Show there is no $2\times2$ matrix such that $B^2=A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a matrix

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}11&-6\\18&-10\end{bmatrix}$$

and have been asked to show that there is no $2\times 2$ matrix $B$ such that $B^2=A$.

My approach has been to define an arbitrary matrix

$$B =\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}$$

which is then squared by itself and equated the result to matrix $A$ and show that this new system of equations is inconsistent. That approach doesn't seem to be working though.

Any suggestions for a better way to proceed?

Comment: **HINT**: Do you know about determinant?

Answer (score 5):

If there is a real $2\times 2$ matrix $B$ with $B^2=A$, then
$$ \det(A)=\det(B^2)=\det(B)^2\geq 0$$
However,
$$ \det(A)=-110+108<0$$

Comment: What if $B$ has complex entries?

Comment: Good point, I assumed that $B$ was real. I suspect that there is a solution to $B^2=A$ if $B$ is allowed to be complex.

Comment: If the question meant to allow complex values, then there is a square root, so the question probably meant a real matrix. (A lot of linear algebra intros don't introduce complex matrices until quite a bit after introducing matrices.)

Comment: Yeah sorry should have specified B is real.